# Не ставится куки PHP

Tags: php

После login.php и переадресации в profile.php, при включённой галочке запомнить, в хедере первым делом устанавливаю куки и далее будут всякие проверки... Проблема в том, что не устанавливается: SetCookie("login",$_SESSION['login'],time()+36000); и соответственно не добавляется в базу. Почему не видно переменную сессии $_SESSION['login']? Сессия же открывается перед этим.

```
<?php 
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); // works
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
session_start(); // запускаем сессию


if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
    
    $qkey = uniqid();
    SetCookie("qkey",$qkey,time()+36000);
    SetCookie("login",$_SESSION['login'],time()+36000);

    // подключение к базе
    include "config.php";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }

    //добавляем qkey
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET qkey = '$qkey' WHERE login = '$login'";
    if($conn->query($sql)){ } else { echo "Ошибка" . $conn->error; }
}
```

Comment: А почему переменная `$_SESSION['login']` вообще должна быть видна? В показанном вами коде не видно, чтобы эта переменная где-то создавалась

Comment: Если SetCookie("login",$_SESSION['login'],time()+36000) вынести выше if, то куки создается корректно, но условие if точно работает и второй куки qkey создается внутри этого ифа, А вот с $_SESSION['login'] внутри иф, какая-то проблема.

Comment: Переформулирую. Почему внутри if не работает echo $_SESSION['login'];? Туда сессия не распространяется что ли?)

Comment: В PHP нет функции SetCookie для установки значение cookie, есть [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: не принципиально и так работает, проблема в том, что $_SESSION['login'] не работает внутри if, а снаружи работает.